# python importlib can't find module with absolute path

Tags: python, path, python-import

Directory structure looks like this:

```
moduleImportTest
|____ main.py
|____ test
      |___ mymod.py
```

I am trying to use `importlib` to import *mymod.py* from *main.py*. At the moment, *main.py* looks like this:

```
import importlib, os
theFile = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/test/mymod.py"
print(theFile)
importlib.import_module(theFile)
```

The `print` statement on line 3 outputs the correct file path (though I've swapped my real name  for "username" in this example:)

```
/home/username/moduleImportTest/test/mymod.py
```

However, line 4 throws an exception:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/home/username/moduleImportTest/test/mymod'
```

I can't work out what's causing this. I'm really at a loss for what to try.

Much of the online information about this suggests that rather than passing a path directly to `importlib`, I should first add the relevant directory to the path using `sys` and then use a regular import statement to import the module normally. The reason I don't want to take this approach is that in the future I want to be able to iterate through a particular directory and import *all* modules in there, regardless of name.

Any idea how I can resolve this? I'm open to trying something completely different to what I'm doing, but only if it maintains the ability to iterate and import all as described above.